# Como poner un Textfield encima de un label en JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy poniendo un label de punta a punta, y en ella estoy poniendo una imagen para que sea la imagen de fondo, pero cuando quiero agregar una caja de txto, se agrega al lado y no encima, viendose de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como haria para que el textfield se vea adelante de la imagen?

Comment: Creo que tal vez sería mejor pintar tu imagen sobre un `JPanel`, en vez de usar un label de esa manera

Comment: y como agregaria una imagen a un jpanel

Comment: Hay varias formas, una de ellas sería creando una clase extendiéndola de `JPanel`, definir tu variable de imagen y dibujandola con el método `paintComponent`, asimismo, la agregas en tu `JFrame` con el método `setContentPane`

Answer (score 1):

Con base en lo que te comenté, la mejor manera de realizar lo que deseas es 'pintando' tu imagen sobre un `JPanel`.

Para esto primero debes crear una clase que se extenderá de un `JPanel`:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public BufferedImage image;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Este se encargará de 'pintar' tu imagen en todo el `JPanel`.

Lo siguiente será 'settear' la imagen que se pintará, y luego 'settear' este `JPanel` sobre el `JFrame`:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

try {
    // Se ajusta la imagen para ser pintada.
    // Aquí debes colocar la dirección de la imagen, normalmente sería la que pusiste en el JLabel.
    panel.image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/stackoverflow/image.jpg"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // En caso de no poder cargarse, hacer algo más...
    System.out.println(e);
}

// Aquí se ajusta el JPanel creado con la imagen pintada en el JFrame
frame.setContentPane(panel);

// Más código irá aquí .....
```

Finalmente, el resultado sería este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]